# ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames

Tags: python, сортировка, csv

```
with open('data.csv', "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

with open('gaze.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    fieldnames = ['gaze_0_x', 'gaze_0_y', 'gaze_0_z', 'gaze_1_x', 'gaze_1_y', 'gaze_2_z']

    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')

    csv_writer.writeheader()

    for line in csv_reader:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

`ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: ' x_59', ' X_18', ' x_27', ' y_42', ' Y_16', ' pose_Rz', ' Y_32', ' Y_54', ' x_26', ' x_16', ' p_5', ' X_67', ' p_14', ' x_17', ' Z_2', '...`
И так далее 400 переменных, которые я **не хочу** задействовать.

Answer (score 3):

Так передайте `fieldnames` в `DictReader`, чтобы он лишних полей не читал.